# How to change the style of a DatePicker in android?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-datepicker, android-timepicker

I want to change the default color of the date/time picker dialog in Android, so that it should match my app's theme. I searched for the solution on Google, but I couldn't find a solution.

What I was doing was creating a new style:

```
  <style name="datepicker" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.DatePicker">
    <!---TODO-->
    <item name="android:focusedMonthDateColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>
```

**Don't know what are the attributes available for date picker dialogue. It would be great if anyone could post a link on that**

and after adding the style I was calling it in my main style as

```
 <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/datepicker</item>
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me at all.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Try this. It's the easiest & most efficient way

```
<style name="datepicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How to set the button style? I tried setting `buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle` `buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle` `buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle` `buttonStyle` but not reflecting.

Comment: I have same issue and can not change button style

Comment: Took no effect with Kotlin.

Answer (score 99):

call like this

```
 button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 DialogFragment dialogfragment = new DatePickerDialogTheme();

 dialogfragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Theme");

 }
 });

public static class DatePickerDialogTheme extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
     int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

//for one

//for two 

 DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK,this,year,month,day);

//for three 
 DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);

// for four

   DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK,this,year,month,day);

//for five

 DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
     AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);

//for six

 DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
 AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL,this,year,month,day);


     return datepickerdialog;
     }

     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){

     TextView textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     textview.setText(day + ":" + (month+1) + ":" + year);

     }
     }
```

follow this it will give you all type date picker style(copy from this)

http://www.android-examples.com/change-datepickerdialog-theme-in-android-using-dialogfragment/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @WolfJee use like this;
                int theme;
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23)
                    theme = AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK;
                else
                        theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog;
 new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), theme, date,......

Comment: very good answer, if you don't want any change in styles and themes of application only for datePicker. But you have just messed up with example images' numbers, e.g .THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT corresponds to second image I think. Also I'm getting now deprecated error for above code for API >23

Comment: I hate the new "Material" style for Google's date picker because users have no fricken clue that the year can be changed by clicking in the top-left corner!! Horrible UX!

Comment: @kaya your suggestion isn't working. Try it on Android 7.0 emulator

Comment: @WolfJee did you find a solution?

Comment: Can I able to change the corner radius?

Comment: These styles are deprecated in API level 23. For updated style constants please refer - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog

Answer (score 64):

To change `DatePicker` colors (calendar mode) at application level define below properties.

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorAccent">#ff6d00</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#33691e</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#d50000</item>
</style>
```

See http://www.zoftino.com/android-datepicker-example for other `DatePicker` custom styles

[image: zoftino DatePicker examples]

Comment: How I can change button text colors?

Comment: @Mahdi see Rohit's answer (that will change the button text color)

Answer (score 61):

Create a new style

```
<style name="my_dialog_theme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>                   <!--header background-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>     <!--calendar background-->
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item> <!--selected day-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item> <!--days of the month-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>    <!--days of the week-->
</style>
```

Then initialize the dialog

```
Calendar mCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
mCalendar.setTime(new Date());

new DatePickerDialog(mContext, R.style.my_dialog_theme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //do something with the date
    }
}, mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: How I can change button style or button text color?

Comment: @Mahdi see Rohit's answer (that will change the button text color)

Comment: what if `DatePicker` is used in xml?

Answer (score 22):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerDialogTheme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(newDate.getTime());
  }
}, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

datePickerDialog.show();
```

And use this style:

```
<style name="DatePickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what if `DatePicker` is used in xml?

Answer (score 12):

Create custom `DatePickerDialog` style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.DatePickerDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Alert.Button.Positive</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Alert.Button.Negative</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/AppTheme.Alert.Button.Neutral</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Alert.Button.Positive" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonPositive</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Alert.Button.Negative" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonNegative</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Alert.Button.Neutral" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/buttonNeutral</item>
</style>
```

Set custom `datePickerDialogTheme` style in app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.DatePickerDialog</item>
</style>
```

Set theme programmatically on initialization like this:

```
val datetime = DatePickerDialog(this, R.style.AppTheme_DatePickerDialog)
```

Comment: Thanks. i was having invisible/white positive and negative buttons before. This fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

(I'm using React Native; targetSdkVersion 22). I'm trying to change the look of a calendar date picker dialog. The accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Hope this snippet helps some of you.

```
<style name="CalendarDatePickerDialog"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#6bf442</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#6bf442</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Isn't it the same code snippet as that of the accepted answer?

Comment: Almost, but the name is different. Setting the name to 'datepicker' didn't work for me, but changing it to 'CalendarDatePickerDialog' made it work.

Answer (score 8):

As `AlertDialog.THEME` attributes are deprecated, while creating `DatePickerDialog` you should pass one of these parameters for `int themeResId`

- **android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_Alert**
- **android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Dialog_Alert**
- **android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert**
- **android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert**

Answer (score 3):

**For DayNight theme:**

1. Create theme for date/time picker:

   ```
   <style name="App.Dialog.DateTime" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
       <item name="colorAccent">?attr/clAccent</item>
       <item name="android:windowBackground">?attr/clPrimary</item>
       <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/App.Dialog.NegativeButton</item>

       <!--  For overScrollMode  -->
       <item name="android:colorEdgeEffect">?attr/clAccentRipple</item>
       <item name="android:overScrollMode">ifContentScrolls</item>
   </style>

   <style name="App.Dialog.NegativeButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
       <item name="android:textColor">?attr/clContentSecond</item>
   </style>
   ```

   You may specify styles for different dialog buttons (like I did it via `App.Dialog.NegativeButton`)

   Also, I tried another parent theme (for `App.Dialog.DateTime`): `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert`, but result looked ugly with strange dialog window sizes.
2. Setup date/time picker theme inside your app theme:

   ```
   <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/App.Dialog.DateTime</item>
   <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/App.Dialog.DateTime</item>
   ```

---

**The result:**

[image: How styled date picker dialog looks]

For more dialog customization you may check xml keys from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56963465/7699617).

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, Possibly because of this style inheritance, `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog` but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a DatePicker in **XML**, all you have to do is adding a style for your dialog as @theBeardedPilot mentioned like this:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <!--header background-->
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <!--selected day-->
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    <!--days of the month-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <!--days of the week-->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

then call this style using the **android:theme** attribute like this:

```
<DatePicker
    android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```