# Change fontcolor of DatePicker Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker, textcolor

I am trying to change the font color of the datepicker, 
I already have been searching but i wasn't able to get a precise answer.
Could you please help me?
My layout is like this:

```
<DatePicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="true"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tb_register_last_name"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bt_register_tostep3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bt_register_tostep3"
    style="@style/MyDatePicker"/>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>

</style>


<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">**@color/CorProfilePi**c</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">**@color/CorProfilePic**</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">**@color/CorProfilePic**</item>


</style>
```

Colors.xml:

```
<resources>
<color name="colorPrimary">#479dcc</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#146ba6</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#0a8da0</color>
<color name="CorProfilePic">#ffffff</color>
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks!
(i'm new at android development)
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the style of Date picker in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239627/how-to-change-the-style-of-date-picker-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT2: This works.** (Added divider color)

> Your XML

```
<DatePicker
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/datePicker"
     android:calendarViewShown="false"
     android:spinnersShown="true"
     android:datePickerMode="spinner"
     android:layout_below="@+id/tb_register_last_name"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bt_register_tostep3"
     android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bt_register_tostep3"
     android:theme="@style/MyDatePicker"/>
```

> In styles.xml, set this (copy-paste the code)

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

Google [materialdoc](http://www.materialdoc.com/date-picker/) will be helpful for you in the future.

Change your style and let me know if it works!!

Comment: Hi Carlos! I i changed, still the same, the datepicker is still black

Comment: @Ko0kiE have you checked the colorPrimary and and colorPrimaryDark value?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works ver nice :P, change the divider color is that easy too?

Comment: @Ko0kiE in your style, if you add a new item and you write "android:", the IDE lets you select an attribute. Try to find your target attribute and modify its color. If you can't find it, let me know!

Comment: Correct. Anyway, I have edited another time my post and if you add in your style code (you have to copy-paste the style, because parent type has changed), the code I have edited, you will see your divider is now green. :)

Comment: Thanks you once again Carlos, you were a big help!!