# Date picker bug

Tags: android

My `DatePickerDialog` doesn't work properly. For example selected day is of white color. Notice that Cancel and OK button are also of white color. How could I change it?

[image: https://tinypic.pl/phfssq7zm5s8]

Here is the code:

```
 fun openCalendar() {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)


    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
            view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->


    }, year, month, day)

    dpd.show()
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

By default datepicker is inheriting color

create style and use different colorAccent you can find details here

[Change DatePicker background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48359176/change-datepicker-background-color)

Answer (score 1):

DatePicker shows highlights with accent color. Looks like you have accent color in theme set to white. Check your color file.