# Materialdatepicker with a spinner style

Tags: android, datepicker, material-design, material-components-android, android-datepicker

Using the default DatePicker class from android it was possible to make the datepicker in form of spinner like this:

[image: spinner]

But with MaterialDesignSpinner it seems that this feature by default is not implemented, as the only form looks like this:

[image: example]

or default textview input.

Did materialdesign remove the spinner feature, or is there a way to implementing it using the MaterialDatePicker?

Comment: For reference, here is the feature request on `MaterialDatePicker` for exactly this.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could't find a solution for the MaterialDatePicker, but I want to share my solution anyways, it works for my purpose it might for yours too:

```
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
            AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,null, 1960, 1, 1);
    dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
    dpd.show();
```

This will display the light version of the date picker dialog.
You can also use:

```
AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK
```

For a dark dialog theme or:

```
android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog
```

For a slightly different dialog itself.
Keep in mind to set **dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);** otherwise the regular calendar part of the picker is shown in addition.
If you look for more variations see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652903/2267367).