# Custom DatePickerDialog in android

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I want to custom a DatePickerDialog, How can I do that?

Thanks for your helping!

Comment: This can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239627/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-datepicker-in-android

Answer (score 1):

This can help: [How to change the style of a DatePicker in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239627/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-datepicker-in-android)

Also, this can be helpful https://www.android-examples.com/change-datepickerdialog-theme-in-android-using-dialogfragment/

Explanation, we are changing the color and style
Let me quote image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWeWU.png]

The above image contains the label for corresponding parts, whose color you can change