# How to change the date picker from spinner to calendar dialogue in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-datepicker

How to change my spinner date picker to normal calendar with an option to keyboard entry as shown in the attached picture

Here is the code.

```
 private val datePickerDialog by lazy {
            DatePickerDialog(requireActivity(), R.style.SpinnerDatePickerDialog).apply {
                setTitle(R.string.select_date)
                datePicker.maxDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1).toMillis()
                setOnDateSetListener { _, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                    viewModel.onDateSelected(year, month, dayOfMonth)
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the style of a DatePicker in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239627/how-to-change-the-style-of-a-datepicker-in-android)

Comment: Thanks, I checked that discussion and looking for a picker with optional keyboard entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below code to achieve a material calendar view.

(1) Add the below dependency in your app Gradle.

**implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'**

(2) Use the below style for your activity.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="ScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar</item>
</style>
```

(3) Set above style in Manifest.xml file with activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/ScreenTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

(4) Add the below code with a button click.

```
val datePicker =
                        MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                                .setTitleText("Select date")
                                .setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
                                .build()

                datePicker.show(childFragmentManager,"")
```

- Use **childFragmentManager** if you want a calendar with fragment otherwise use **supportFragmentManager** with activity.

Output:
[image]

Comment: I am still having trouble to add a click button action to it...may be missing something in my code to work properly. Let me try again. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I got it working now.